# Display html page in webview and get interact with that html page

Tags: iphone

Hi All can some one help me ,I am new to iPhone .
  My requirement is I have to display HTML Page in webview .So if i click one button then it should go to another view .So How i can i do it ,

Answer (score 0):

Your button points to a `whatever://dosomething` URL, and your webview's delegate intercepts this in its `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method. Returning NO and doing something based on the URL should allow you to do what you're trying.